# What's the difference between nmap -v and nmap -O?

Tags: nmap, ubuntu

As I'm a newbie in this, I'm unaware of the differences between making a scan using 
`nmap -v localhost` and `nmap -O localhost`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These (-v and -O) are listed in the basic option summary have you RTFM?

Comment: @R15 yes i went through this http://nmap.org/book/man-examples.html but was a bit confused!

Comment: Look here next time: http://nmap.org/book/man-briefoptions.html or just typing nmap at the command line with no args shoudl bring up the same info.

Comment: That looks great! So will i be able to block any open port even?

Answer (score 2):

`-v` stands for Verbose, meaning NMAP will attempt to tell you what it is doing. You'd typically add this option to see if something is malfunctioning, or if you're curious. NMAP supports the "levels of verbosity" trope in some unix commands. `-v` is level one. `-vv` is level two, so it tells you more than level one. `-vvv` is even more. The fun part is "how many levels does this support?" Occasionally there are Easter eggs: the program may tell you to cut it out after a bit!

`-O` tells NMAP to attempt to guess the operating system of the machine it's scanning.

I assume you are learning nmap on a Linux system? if at any time you have a question about commands, type `man <name of command>` and a help screen will appear. `/` lets you search (`n` to advance to the next result) and `q` quits to the command line. That's how I answered this question, and you can answer other questions like in the future using man :)

Answer (score 1):

`nmap -v` states it to be verbose. If what you wanted to know was `nmap -sV`, it tells nmap to try to discover the service version, for example, try to figure out if something running on port tcp 80 is really an http server or something else.

`nmap -O` tries to fingerprint the OS version. For example, is the scanned machine a Windows XP, Windows 7, Linux kernel 3.0, OpenBSD, etc.